# How to resolve login fail 'Your currnt session has been expired.' into admin pape in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, onepage-checkout, session, php-7

Using Magento CE 2.2.0 with sample data. this error happen when i change time zone in 'bootstrap.php', i try to change it back in it still error.

[image]

Comment: Check my answer and try it.

Comment: Thank very much @Nikunj Vadariya.

Comment: Hi bong, if my answer solves your concern then there is green right tick mark , hit that tickmark for right ansewer that will help future readers.

Answer (score 2):

It's occurred due to MySql TIMESTAMP and MySql version issue.

Here is the solution which helps you to overcome the admin login issue of the session.

**Go to : `admin_user_session` table in MySql Set `created_at` column to '0' and `updated_at` column to '`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`' as it is.**

Refresh admin page and try to log in again, it will work.